# safe publication via a final method argument?

Tags: java, multithreading

*Java Concurrency in Practice* describes several ways to ensure that an object is safely published, one of which is "assignment to a final field of a properly constructed object". My question is whether assignment to a final method argument is sufficient to ensure safe publication. Consider the following code:

```
private void collectResults() {
    runOnBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            displayResults(someBlockingMethodCall());
        }
    });
}

private void displayResults(final List<Foo> results) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            someUiMethodCall(results);
        }
    });
}
```

Each method queues a `Runnable` for execution on another thread. `someBlockingMethodCall()` is called on the background thread to perform some task, and `someUiMethodCall()` is called on the UI thread to display the results.

If we assume that `someBlockingMethodCall()` returns a mutable, unsynchronized list, such as an ArrayList, does assignment to the final argument of `displayResults()` ensure that the list is safely published, or do I need to take extra steps to ensure safe publication?

Comment: It's only `final` fields that matter. For method arguments as well as local variables (which are basically the same), the only thing that you get is an error when you try to reassign a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually fine here. The only time you need to really worry about it if you write the `results` to a shared variable that is not synchronized.

To hand it off to a thread there should usually be some synchronization in general. For instance, if you started a thread and the `results` was passed to the Runnable, the `start` of the thread is the sync point you'd need.

In this case, you are invoking `runOnUiThread`, there is a synchronization point from the moment you submit the `results` to the point where a thread picks it up.

So the submission here will be thread safe.

Comment: Thank you John! It hadn't occurred to me that of course the methods handing off the object between the background and UI threads must be using synchronization, and therefore the object would be safely published without any extra precautions.

Comment: @akwizgran Glad to help. I always say that one finally understands multi threaded programming when they are overtly paranoid of multi threaded programming :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several misconceptions here. The `final` field publication guaranty is given to allow the programmer to assume correctly working immutable objects even if they are improperly published. This does not imply that you should design your software around improperly published objects.

Normally, the `runOnUiThread` and `runOnBackgroundThread` should post the `Runnable` instances to the executing thread in a thread-safe way, hence, there is no need to rely on the `final` field publication. Whether these two methods do it correctly, is impossible for us to tell as you didn’t post their code.

Further, the guaranty applies to, as you correctly cited, an “assignment to a final field of a properly constructed object” and local variables (which includes parameters) are not fields of any constructed object. But this isn’t something to worry about as parameters are, as any local variable, *local* to the thread executing the method, hence, not published at all.

There’s a corner case here as you are *capturing* the value of the local variable when creating an instance of the anonymous `Runnable` implementation. This capturing has indeed the `final` field assignment semantics, and that regardless of whether the parameter has been declared `final` or is just *effectively final*.

But, as said, that shouldn’t drive your software design. You should ensure that `runOnUiThread` and `runOnBackgroundThread` do publish their runnables properly instead of thinking about final field publication. If these methods don’t publish the provided runnables properly, other problems may occur, but if they do, the publication of any object referenced by the runnables are properly published as well. This all assuming that you don’t modify the list after publication.

Comment: As a new user my upvotes aren't visible, so I just wanted to say thank you Holger for this very informative answer, especially the detail about the semantics of captured fields.